# Mysteriously flipped bits in a Cython function after casting to 32-bit integer

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython

I have a fiddly Cython function that's started behaving very strangely over the last 72 hours.

We're doing some things with a sparse COO matrix that require looping over the column indices of the COO representation of the matrix. Because I want to do this quickly, I'm sticking the extracted column values into a typed C variable like this:

```
ranked_groups = A[local_ranked,:].tocoo()
ranked_groups_col_c = ranked_groups.col.astype(np.int32)
```

The strange thing is that sometimes the contents of `ranked_groups_col_c` are getting scrambled. That is, `ranked_groups_col_c` should only be able to contain values from 0 to the columns of the variable `A`. For example, if A is 100x100, we would expect the values of `ranked_groups_col_c` to be between 0 and 99.

Using a debugger, I've confirmed that the column contents of the pre-cast variable `ranked_groups` are indeed bounded by the column count.

Whereas about 9 out of 10 times we use this code, some of the values in `ranked_groups_col_c` (after casting) look to me like they've had bits randomly scrambled. For example, with a COO matrix of 208621 columns, I've logged cases like this:

```
>>> 280205 208621
>>> 1120897 208621
>>> 891677560 208621
>>> 891677560 208621
```

where the first number is the index in `ranked_groups_col_c` (which should never be beyond the column count) and the second is, for reference, the number of columns in the source matrix.

I've tried upgrading NumPy to the latest version and to past versions, and this keeps happening. We've also reached out to our cloud provider, and they haven't written back. I have to think this is some very low-level bug, but not clear to me what that might be.

Update: we're a little hesitant to post the whole function, but here's a snippet including the variable declaration:

```
# the matrix A is an argument of the function

ranked = np.argsort(-scores).astype(np.int32)

seen = np.zeros(A.shape[1], dtype=np.int32)
cdef int[:] seen_c = seen
cdef int[:] local_ranked_c
cdef int[:] ranked_groups_col_c

for i in range(n):
    local_ranked = ranked[i,:]
    local_ranked_c = local_ranked

    ranked_groups = A[local_ranked,:].tocoo()
    ranked_groups_col_c = ranked_groups.col.astype(np.int32)

    for pos in range(m):
        j = local_ranked_c[pos]
        k = ranked_groups_col_c[pos]

        if seen_c[k]:
            pass
```

Comment: Is it possible to also post the cython code, or would this be too complex (or sensitive)? Do you also get this when using test inputs, say, the 100 x 100 matrix from your example?

Comment: I'll have to spend some time obscuring sensitive parts of the code, but I can try to post the source in the question. The glitch isn't happening in our test suite (which uses smaller datasets). It's also not happening on one image deployed with this code two weeks ago, which is why I think it might be a machine problem.

Comment: I suspect this isn't answerable without code, however in the short-term could you at least show how `ranked_groups_col_c` is typed?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Python installation (i.e. is it a 64-bit installation?), there could be problems casting to 32-bit integers. For a 64-bit Python interpreter, integers are 64-bit wide (unlike `int` for e.g. x86_64 C compilers, which is 32-bit wide). If a single 64-bit Python integer is cast to 32 bits on a machine with little endian ordering (such as 64-bit Intel), the 32 higher bits are simply chopped off, which is fine if the integer isn't larger than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 or less than -2<sup>31</sup> (the higher bits should all be zeros or ones for positive or negative integers then). However, if larger magnitude integers should occur, the 32bit conversion will lead to errors. If the C part of the code should access an array of 64-bit-wide Python integers as an array of 32-bit integers, all but the index of the zeroth element would be wrong.

Is casting to `long` on 64-bit installations of Linux and OSX, or to `long long` on 64-bit MS Windows installations an option?

Comment: Yes, it's a 64-bit install of Python. I could definitely try to avoid casting by using a long, but that seemed silly when I was writing this. (Maybe safer to do as little as possible!) As far as I know the biggest values that would be cast would be order 2^19.

Comment: Besides the magnitude of integers, wrong indexing (i.e. expecting a new integer in an array every 32bits, in case the integers are really 64bit wide), is a more general problem. Impossible to say without the Cython code. However, the automatically generated Cython code (without manually added casts, if I understand correctly) does work?

Comment: Yes, this is really a weird one. I've added what I think the the relevant snippet of code without having to worry about accidentally sharing too much. The issue with the changing element size doesn't quite square with the fact this bug appears to happen non-deterministically. E.g., deploying this code in more than one place the same function call shifts different values to different values.